# R and Error Handling

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm trying to get a grip on exception handling in R, or exception handling as a whole.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672351/exception-handling-and-stack-unwinding-in-r) which was useful in the first place. But now I don't know how I should handle a specific problem. Let's say we we have a list of Variables and I want the user to select (via svDialogs) one of these.

```
require(svDialogs)
var<-c("A","B","C","D")
var1<-dlgList(var,multiple=FALSE)$res
```

If the user selects nothing or hits `cancel` R returns an empty character string. I want to program to throw an error if that happens and quits the program. How can I achieve that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if(length(var1)==0) stop("My error message)`

Comment: thx, I thought maybe I could do it with `TryCatch` to avoid `if`-statements

Comment: There is no error, just an empty string, so `tryCatch` doesn't help.

Comment: Okey, thank you. Can you write it as answer then I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To throw an error, do some custom validation, then use `stop()`:

For example:

```
if(length(var1)==0) stop("My error message)
```

---

Since your original code doesn't contain errors, just an empty string, `tryCatch` or any of the other error catching mechanisms doesn't help in your case.